# Image scale/move/skew controls

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I need to move/scale/skew image (or text) using javascript. I know how to do this using CSS3 but all this actions should be dynamic and with controls. Like this:

[image]

I found fabricjs

- http://fabricjs.com/controls/
- http://fabricjs.com/customization/

But I also need action for **skew**.

Any JS library / exapmle that could do it?

Comment: There is skew translate available natively with the canvas element, but that probably requires you to write all the logic from scratch unless the library allows you to insert your own code into the pipe-line (I am not familiar with the library so I can't tell).

Comment: Only pure javascript or jquery plugin will do too?

Comment: @Ken I know about canvas skew but I need controls for this action. User should be able to skew images in real time using mouse :)

Comment: @Vijeta any lib, any plugin. This is not matter

Comment: fwiw, we are planning to add skew in Fabric in the near future

Comment: it would be perfect. Right now I am going to use LibCanvas because there is a "perspective" function (not skew but similar) just from the box. But Fabric has better docs and examples and I think it would be better to use Fabric. But right now I dunno how to do all what I need with Fabric :(

Comment: 2 years later fabric skew Support has been added.

Answer (score 0):

check the jQuery plugin :

[jquery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

Usage seems simple too.

```
$('.box').transition({ rotate: '45deg' });
$('.box').transition({ scale: 2.2 });
$('.box').transition({ skewX: '30deg' });
$('.box').transition({ x: 40, y: 40 });
```

Comment: Yeah. it is simple but it provide only methods to change object. Same could be done using only CSS3 rules. But in this way I need to implement controls (controls - i mean this little squares http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbhEe.png)

Comment: In place of the boxes it could be your text or any div. $("#div_id").transition({ skewX: '30deg' });